# how to get only one value from an array?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this view :

```
        @foreach($recent_posts as $rp)
        <div class="blogPostClassic">
            <div class="blogThumb">
                <ul class="bxsliderBlog">
                    @foreach($rp->photos as $rpt)
                    <li><img src="{{route('getPostImages', $rpt->image)}}" alt="" /></li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
                <div class="thumbBar"></div>
            </div>
            <table border="1" class="blogDetails">
                <tr>
                    <td><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($rp->created_at)->format('j F Y') }}</td>
                    <td><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> {{$rp->views}}</td>
                    <td><i class="fa fa-comments"></i> 20</td>
                </tr>
            </table><br>
            <h1 style="font-size:calc(95% + 1.2vw);"><a href="#">{{$rp->title}}</a></h1>
            <p>Posted by <a href="#">Sandra</a> in <a href="#">{{$rp->category->title}}</a></p>
            <p></p><br/>
            <a href="#" class="button blog">READ MORE</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dividerWidget"></div>
        @endforeach
```

The `$rp->photos` contains an array of images that belonged to each post. How to only take one image for each post from the array so that I don't have to use carousel too much ?

The index method :

```
public function index() {
    $recent_posts = Post::with(['category', 'tags'])->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
    return view('pages/home', compact('recent_posts', $recent_posts));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `$i=0;` variable like this

```
<?php  $i=0; ?>
 @foreach($recent_posts as $rp)

    ........
    <li><img src="{{route('getPostImages', $rp->photos[$i]->image)}}" alt="" /></li>
   ........

 @endforeach
```

Comment: It works great, thank you. But you misplaced `<?php  $i=0; ?>`

Comment: glad to help you @SandraVioletta

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `first()` method. So in your code it should be:

```html
    @foreach($recent_posts as $rp)
    ......
      <li><img src="{{route('getPostImages', $rp->photos->first()->image)}}" alt="" /></li>
    .......       
    @endforeach
```

Or you can initiate it in variable first:

```php
    @foreach($recent_posts as $rp)

    <?php $photo = $rp->photos->first() ?>
    ......
      <li><img src="{{route('getPostImages', $photo->image)}}" alt="" /></li>
    .......       
    @endforeach
```

Comment: The first one works great as well and simpler. Thanks!

Comment: Terimakasih bang, sayang keduluan yang di atas jadi gak bisa aku tandai benar j